# creating alternate state/territory/county fields when a country is changed within a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have just noticed a serious bug within my payment form. When someone changes their country from the select field, it automatically replaces the 'county' text field with a 'states' select box (if country=US), or 'territories' select box (if country=Canada). This is done through ajax.

```
$('#billing_country').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==223) {
        $.ajax({        
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : '//localhost/mslv2/ajax/states.php',
            data    : 'type=billing',
            success : function(data) {
                $("#billing_country_div").html(data);
            }
        }); 
    };
});
```

the states.php file

```
$states = '<label for="'.$_POST['type'].'_county">State*</label>
<select name="'.$_POST['type'].'_county">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select a State</option>';
$state_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `zone_code`,`zone_name` FROM `zones` WHERE `zone_country_id`=223");
while($state_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($state_qry)) {
    $states .= '<option value="'.$state_row['zone_code'].'">'.$state_row['zone_name'].'</option>';
}
$states .= '</select>';
echo $states;
```

So I have noticed that when the form submits, that because the fields are coming in on the fly, they are not being picked up when the form submits, creating errors.

One solution I thought, was that if e.g. Canada was selected, then I could refresh the page, but then I still couldnt think on how to pass that through to the php code, to know to show the Canadian territories.

One other solution is keep the

```
<input type="text" id="billing_county" name="billing_county" value="<?php echo $billing_county; ?>" />
```

text field, and hide it, and then show these select boxes, and have their value update into the text field, which should work. But I was wondering if there was a better simpler solution to this.

Comment: Hint: `billing_county` - Check your spelling for all of them.

Comment: Please re-read the question, spelling all correct.

Comment: why don't you use a different name, instead of billing_country for both, also instead of hiding a text input you would use a hidden input (`<input type=hidden>`)

Comment: By default it is county - the site is based in the UK county is the UK equivalent of State. It is displayed there, so shouldnt be hidden. I was thinking when the states show, it could be hidden, and then the value could be entered into there. Is that the best solution?

Comment: I see `id="billing_county"` then I see `('#billing_country')` - So, you can re-read your code and tell me there isn't a typo. You don't have an "id" called "billing_country", or is that "elsewhere"?

Comment: <input type="text" id="billing_county" - see, id billing county. There is an id billing_country as well for the countries drop down.

Comment: Fair enough. I saw `$('#billing_country')` which threw me off.

Comment: Ok, so I guess no one can answer it? And I came up with the best solution.